# How to map exception to response status code without explicit controller advice method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have several applications with duplicate code in them. We're talking 90% identical, and it's critical shared functionality. Right now I am refactoring it all into re-usable libraries.

The applications in question use either Spring Boot or Jersey (older ones). Because of this, I'm creating multiple libraries. The first is the Core library, where almost all of the logic is. Then I'm creating a Spring Boot wrapper and a Jersey wrapper, which combine the core code with framework-specific bindings.

All of this is well and good, but I just hit a roadblock. I have these exceptions that are mapped to specific HTTP Status Codes with the `@ResponseStatus` annotation. I want to move these into the Core library, but that means the spring-specific annotations need to be dropped. Then I want the Spring library to map those exceptions to the status codes.

My first thought was to use `@ControllerAdvice`, but in my experience that is for building an entire response payload, and I want the error response payload shape to be controlled by the consuming application, rather than the library.

My second thought was to wrap the logic throwing these exceptions with try/catch, and re-throw them as spring exceptions. I don't like having to explicitly handle every place the exceptions are used, though.

I'm hoping someone can share with me another option for accomplishing this. This is for Spring, but it's possible I may need to ask a similar question for Jersey, I haven't looked at how this is handled on the Jersey side yet.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you need, but have a look here https://github.com/zalando/problem-spring-web

Comment: What do you mean by that? ` but in my experience that is for building an entire response payload, and I want the error response payload shape to be controlled by the consuming application, rather than the library.`